# Chrome extension to access page source of the current website

Tags: html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I was wondering if the Chrome extension could access the source code of what the user is currently visiting.

For example, if the user is visiting http://www.google.com, is there a way where the extension  can access the site's DOM.

Thank you.